# How to make alpha-numeric strings stay the way I type them, whether they are all numbers except for the E

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet, vba

I'm working in Excel 2013. I'm running a SQL query that is generating a lot of Alpha-Numeric strings. I paste them in to Excel and mostly it's fine. But there are some that are all numbers except for a single 'E' towards the end. Excel is turning these into scientific notation or if I make the cells anything else it adds a lot of zero's as if it was scientific notation and is now text. For example one number that I'm working on is: 33161E57
What Excel shows is either 3.3161E+59 or 331610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
This is really annoying as I have some 72000 strings and can't correctly sort and parse them unless they are all correctly being shown as just plain text the way they are entered. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Format the cell as Text prior to entering numbers. Rgds,

Comment: Or use a `'` before the string

Comment: I have tried both of those suggestions, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I opened a new spread sheet and copied all the data into it then saved it as a .csv file. This has different formatting restrictions and I was able to keep everything the way I entered it and still be able to sort and parse everything.

Thank you to those who tried to help.